Data Validation google sheets partial match
I have a tab in Google sheets with vehicle data coming from a google form. I made another tab to filter these data using a data validation. The validations are Car 1, Car 2, Car 3, Truck 1, Truck 2, Truck 3.
This works perfectly. I'd like to know if I can add "Car" to the list which would pull Car 1, Car 2 and Car 3 at the same time.
Is it possible?

Use QUERY() function.
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:C,"where C contains '" & D1 &"'")



Simple, I was stuck in the validation so did not think about the "Filter" formula
